# Write Excel file from rdl/rdlc file in Windows application

Tags: c++, excel, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I have **rdl** files made by Report Builder 3.0. I need to use them in my Windows application written in C++ in way so that I am able to set SQL Server connection parameters and Report location at runtime.

Is this possible and how?

*Google told me* that I need to convert **rdl** to **rdlc** file, but even then I couldn't find a way of setting these parameters and calling **rdlc** file from C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReportViewer and use RDL or RDLC files but RDL could have some limitations since it doesn't  include necessary information to create data-binding code.

> RDL files do not contain some information that the design-time of the
>   ReportViewer control depends on for automatically generating
>   data-binding code. By manually binding data, RDL files can be used in
>   the ReportViewer control.

You can set the parameters from ReportViewer, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252663(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) documentation and the below code example in C#:

```
private void SetReportParameters() {
   // Set Processing Mode
   reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

   // Set report server and report path
   reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new
      Uri("http://<ServerName>/reportserver");

   reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = 
      "/AdventureWorks Sample Reports/Employee Sales Summary";

   List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();

   paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("EmpID", "288", false));
   paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportMonth", "12", false));
   paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportYear", "2003", false));

   this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);

   // Process and render the report
   reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

This is an example of `ReportViewer` usage to generate Excel files:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;

            byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
               "Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
                out extension,
               out streamids, out warnings);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\output.xls",
               FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Close();

            Label1.Text = "Report exported to output.xls";
}
```

Let me know if this can help you.